# How to document individual actions of a ViewSet using `drf-spectacular`?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, redoc, drf-spectacular

Using DRF's built-in way of documenting the API, I was able to write a docstring like the following and each action was documented by its corresponding line:

```
"""
list:    The list action returns all available objects.
retrieve:The retrieve action returns a single object selected by `id`.
create:  The create action expects the fields `name`, creates a new object and returns it.
"""
```

I am in the middle of switching to the library `drf-spectacular`, which allows for an easy generation of OpenAPI conforming schemes. However, the same docstring is now rendered for every action, which makes my documentation really long and redundant.

Is there a way that only the relevant part of the docstring is rendered for each action?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just found out that the library provides very in-depth documentation functionality via their decorators. Without overriding any of the ViewSet methods, the above docstring could be written as:

```
@extend_schema_view(
    list=extend_schema(
        description="The list action returns all available actions."
    ),
    create=extend_schema(
        description="The create action expects the fields `name`, creates a new object and returns it."
    ),
    retrieve=extend_schema(
        description="The retrieve action returns a single object selected by `id`."
    )
)
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    pass
```